# Array.map render identical titles once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arraylist, array-map

I have passwords array, I want to display those passwords - each password has a resource which should be displayed once as a title
So:
take resource as a title:

**resource1: - password1 - password2 - password0**,

**resource2: - password4 - passwords5,**

**resource3: - password6 - password7 - password8 - password9**

```
        this.state.passwords && this.state.passwords.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <>
                    {item[index] !== item[index + 1] && (  //here I am trying to do this logic
                        <Nav.Item><div className="sidebar-heading-secrets">{item.resource}</div></Nav.Item>
                    )}
                    <span>We render data here</span>
                </>
            )
        })
    }``
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing key in map. Use React.Fragment and supply a key

```
this.state.passwords && this.state.passwords.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                    {item[index] !== item[index + 1] && (  //here I am trying to do this logic
                        <Nav.Item><div className="sidebar-heading-secrets">{item.resource}</div></Nav.Item>
                    )}
                    <span>We render data here</span>
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        })
    }``
```

Comment: Is this answer answers my question?!! I want to display the title that is supplied by multiple items once only for the first item, of course, if the items have the same title, this is an example from my code.